# Line integral with Mobius transformation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> **Corollary:** If $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $\overline{B}(a;r)\subset G$
>   then $$f^{(n)}(a)=\dfrac{n!}{2\pi i} \int
>  \limits_{\gamma}\dfrac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw,$$ where
>   $\gamma(t)=a+re^{it}$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi.$

Using the above corollary find the following integral: $$\int \limits_{\gamma}\dfrac{dz}{(z-\frac{1}{2})^n},$$ where $n\geq 1, \gamma(t)=e^{it}, t\in [0,2\pi]$.

**Remark:** I know that this problem can be solved easily using residues but the purpose of this problem is use the above corollary.

**My approach:** Define the mapping $w=T(z)$ with $T(z)=\dfrac{2z-1}{z-2}$ then we know that this maps unit disk onto unit disk with $T(1/2)=0$. Also we can show that  $z=T^{-1}(w)=\dfrac{2w-1}{w-2}$.

Let's make substitution in our integral and we get the following: $$\int \limits_{\gamma}\dfrac{d(\frac{2w-1}{w-2})}{\left(\dfrac{2w-1}{w-2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}=\int \limits_{\gamma}\dfrac{2(w-2)-(2w-1)}{(w-2)^2} : \left( \dfrac{4w-2-w+2}{2(w-2)}\right)^ndw=$$$$=-2^n\int \limits_{\gamma} \dfrac{(w-2)^{n-2}}{w}dw =$$

If $f(w)=(w-2)^{n-2}$ then it clearly analytic on unit disk  and we can apply our corollary: $$=-2^n\times 2\pi i \times f(0)=(-1)^{n-1}2^{n+1}\pi i.$$

Can anyone please check it and say is my solution correct? Especially the answer.

Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: It is not clear why you are using transformation. Just let $f(z) = 1$ and compute $f^{(n-1)}({1 \over 2})$.

Comment: @copper.hat, are you sure? I am asking this because in this case your curve should be smth like $\gamma(t)=1/2+re^{it}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, but in my the curve is just unit circle with center at origin

Comment: There is a nice homotopy between the two curves...

Comment: @copper.hat, unfortunately i am not familiar with notion of homotopy :(

Comment: Are you familiar with Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: @copper.hat, could you clarify what do you mean by Cauchy integral formula? I have noticed that different books call it differently. For example wiki says that the corollary which i put above is called Cauchy integral formula!

Comment: Sorry, not ignoring you, just really busy :-(. I meant Cauchy integral theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem.

Comment: You need to change the curve $\gamma$. Even though the trace of the curves is the same, $\gamma$ and $T \circ \gamma$ are different curves.

Answer (score 1):

This is really about complex integrals of homotopic curves. The following
is a proof based on a simple version of Cauchy's integral theorem 
applied to this specific case.

Excuse the rude picture. It is easier to describe the curves below using
a diagram than with symbols.

$\lambda$ is a circle of radius ${1}$ centered on ${0}$.
$\gamma$ is a circle of radius ${1\over 4}$ centered on ${1 \over 2}$.
**Note**: After drawing the pictures, I realised that I should have swapped
$\gamma,\lambda$.

Let $\epsilon$ be a small real number. Let $l_\epsilon$ be the line (curve) joining the points where the line $\operatorname{im} z = \epsilon$
intersects the circles $\lambda, \gamma$. Let $\gamma_\epsilon, \lambda_\epsilon$ be the portion of the circles $\lambda, \gamma$ that start and end where the lines $l_\epsilon, l_{-\epsilon}$ intersect
the circles $\lambda, \gamma$.

[image]

Suppose $h$ is a continuous function defined on some open $U$,
suppose $h$ has an antiderivative $H$, that is, $H' = h$, and
suppose $c$ is a closed, piecewise differentiable curve in $Y$,
then the fundamental theorem of calculus shows that $\int_c h dz  = 0$.

Let $g_n(z) = {1 \over (z-{1\over 2})^n}$, for $n =1,2...$. Note that
the $g_n$ are smooth on $\{ {1 \over 2} \}^c$.

Also note that
$z \mapsto \log (z-{1 \over 2})$ is an antiderivative of $g_1$ and it
is straightforward to compute antiderivatives of $g_2,g_3$, etc. Note that
these are all smooth on $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,{1 \over 2}]$.`

In particular, $\int_{\gamma_\epsilon+(-l_\epsilon)+(-\gamma_\epsilon)+l_{- \epsilon}} g_n dz = 0$.

A small amount of work shows that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} g_n dz = \int_{\gamma} g_n dz$, similarly for $\lambda, \lambda_\epsilon$ and also
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (\int_{-l_\epsilon} g_ndz + \int_{l_{-\epsilon}} g_ndz) = 0$.

Combining these shows that $\int_\gamma g_n dz = \int_\lambda g_n dz$.

Hence $\int_\lambda g_n dz = \int_\gamma {1 \over (z - {1\over 2})^n} dz = {2 \pi i \over (n-1)!} 1^{(n-1)}({1 \over 2})$, where I am abusing notation by using $1$ to represent the function $z \mapsto 1$.

In particular, the value is $2 \pi i$ for $n=1$ and zero otherwise.